# Select both row number and count from oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pagination

I'm trying to select records with pagination, and I need the total number of records so that I can display the number of records and pages on the UI.

The query I'm using is as below but it always returning the totalcount as 1.

```
WITH cteEmp AS 
  (SELECT e.empid, e.empname, d.deptid, d.deptname
     FROM hr.Emp e
    INNER JOIN hr.dept d ON e.deptid = d.deptid)
Select * from (SELECT row_number() over (order by hr.empid desc) rn, Count(*) totalcount, 
                C.empName FROM CTEPO C
                LEFT JOIN hr.emphistory ON C.empid=hr.empid
                GROUP BY c.empid,hr.empid)  where rn>0 and rn<= 100
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for a minimal example of your table; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data; and your expected output for that sample data.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this maybe it'll work for you:

```
(SELECT e.empid, e.empname, d.deptid, d.deptname
     FROM hr.Emp e
    INNER JOIN hr.dept d ON e.deptid = d.deptid)
Select * from (SELECT row_number() over (order by hr.empid desc) rn,
 count(*) OVER (ORDER BY hr.empid desc ) AS totalcount
               C.empName FROM CTEPO C
               LEFT JOIN hr.emphistory ON C.empid=hr.empid
                GROUP BY c.empid,hr.empid)  where rn>0 and rn<= 100
```